# Convert JSON date string

Tags: php, json

I am trying to display date string from JSON that looks like:

```
/Date(1115190000000-0700)/
```

By performing a php echo statement:

```
<?php
  $date = $contract['ContractResult'][0]['ContractDate']; //which is /Date(1115190000000-0700)/
  echo $date;
?>
```

My JSON is coming from WCF if that matters.

Comment: What is the problem? `echo` seems to work just fine. What does your script do, and what do you _want_ it to do?

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to parse it. This requires you to find out what `1115190000000` and what `0700` means. The latter part might be some UTC offset (I'm just guessing)?

Once you have a timestamp, you can:

```
echo date('d.m.Y', $timestamp);
```

BTW: I found out that `1115190000` is `04.05.2005`. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Thank you, that is the correct date in our database. I will try to parse my $date to your $timestamp.